# Is there a way to convert a .PAR file extension to a .AVI or .MP4 using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert .PAR files to .AVI or .MP4 using FFMPEG. However, when I try to convert to .AVI it's giving me the following error:

- [mpeg4 @ 0000000000702200] header damaged. Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input.

When I try to convert the .PAR to .MP4, it completes the conversion but the outputted footage will be all scrambled and oddly enough it will include frames from other channels(cameras).

Is there a way how I can successfully convert .PAR file to .AVI or .MP4, please?

*** UPDATE ***
Apparently .PAR extension can contain more than just 1 channel(cameras) and are synced by time. Therefore, multiple cameras can be viewed at once. Is there a way how to first separate these synced channels?

Comment: Please don’t ask new questions in the comments. I you have another question, please make a new post.

Comment: Managed to edit the current question, thanks.